# Walking through cases with for loop

Tags: php, html, css, switch-statement, case

Good day all,

I'm currently working on a website that I want to have its background changed with each type of weather it currently is in Hoogeveen (Dutch city).

The temperature imported through the station of Hoogeveen is set in a variable and ready to use.

Now my question:

I am writing a case for every weathercode that is given. Every code requires a different lay-out at the website therefor a different CSS.

So, this is how it currently looks like (it's a part of the code).

Is it possible to use a for loop, since the case value and the Type_xx.css are both adding up in same speed?

```
<?php 
        getWeatherStringHoogeveen(); 
        $TypeStyleSheet = '';
        switch ($tempCode) {
            case 5:
            $TypeStyleSheet = "CSS/WeerType_05.css"; break; 
            case 6:
            $TypeStyleSheet = "CSS/WeerType_06.css"; break; 
            case 7:
            $TypeStyleSheet = "CSS/WeerType_07.css"; break; 
            case 8: 
            $TypeStyleSheet = "CSS/WeerType_08.css"; break; 
            case 9: 
            $TypeStyleSheet = "CSS/WeerType_09.css"; break; 
            case 10: 
            $TypeStyleSheet = "CSS/WeerType_10.css"; break; 
            case 11: 
            $TypeStyleSheet = "CSS/WeerType_11.css"; break; 
            case 12: 
            $TypeStyleSheet = "CSS/WeerType_12.css"; break; 
            case 13:
            $TypeStyleSheet = "CSS/WeerType_13.css"; break; 
            case 14:
            $TypeStyleSheet = "CSS/WeerType_14.css"; break; 
            case 15:
            $TypeStyleSheet = "CSS/WeerType_15.css"; break; 
            case 16:
            $TypeStyleSheet = "CSS/WeerType_16.css"; break; 
        }
        echo ' <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.$TypeStyleSheet.'"> ';                                                    // . geeft tussenruimte voor een variabele 
    ?>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: The question is not obvious from the text above - please clarify

Comment: It appears that the only thing that changes within the `switch` statement is the integer value of the stylesheet. It would be simpler perhaps to simply use `$TypeStyleSheet = "CSS/WeerType_{$tempCode}.css";`

Comment: Sorry I missed out the question itself but I had to leave, so I did not notice up untill now. Now that I'm back I have made the edits.

Comment: @RamRaider You're right... I feel a bit stupid not seeing this option earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build the css filename easier, without the need of a `switch` or a `for` loop, see example

```
$tempCode = 4; // using an example value

$digits = str_pad($tempCode, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

$TypeStyleSheet = "CSS/WeerType_$digits.css";

print $TypeStyleSheet;
//outputs
//CSS/WeerType_04.css
```

Comment: You are welcome. It doesn't really matter where it comes from, I just gave it a value in order to run the test. As long as the values are from 0 until 99 it will work correctly.

Comment: @MwB: why does it matter how $tempCode is set?

Comment: also, remember to accept the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Wow such quick answers, thanks already for the quickiness of your reply. Got the intention, and fixed it. Thanks!